What Mechanisms Are Used to Cause Selenium/OpenWPM Crawlers to Time Out Excessively and Exit?
I’m using Selenium and OpenWPM to crawl and interact with web pages. On certain websites, all elements appear to load successfully, but when I try to grab a specific element (with a certain attribute) and perform a click, the instruction causes a timeout.
Here are some observations:
The elements are dynamically generated, and their classes are non-static (i.e., they change on every page load).
Despite the page visually appearing fully loaded, attempting to locate the element using its attribute results in a long delay or a timeout.
I suspect this might be due to some dynamic behavior or intentional obfuscation to disrupt automated tools.
I’ve tried the following approaches, but they haven’t fully solved the issue:
Using WebDriverWait with presence_of_element_located to ensure the element is loaded before interacting with it.
Attempting to locate the element by alternative attributes or XPath.
Trying execute_script to interact with the element directly via JavaScript.
Questions:
What techniques do websites use to make elements dynamically generated in this way, causing timeouts for automated tools?
How can I effectively handle this behavior and interact with elements that have non-static attributes?
Any advice, insights, or recommendations for debugging this problem would be greatly appreciated!

You may follow these below:

Enhanced Waiting Strategies:

Use WebDriverWait with expected_conditions like visibility_of_element_located, element_to_be_clickable, or custom conditions to handle dynamic delays.

Robust Locators:

Avoid relying on class names or IDs that are non-static.
Use XPath or CSS selectors based on unique combinations of attributes or parent-child relationships.

Handle AJAX Delays:

Wait for specific JavaScript variables or network requests to complete using execute_script or libraries like requests in Python.

JavaScript Interaction:

If standard Selenium methods fail, use execute_script to directly manipulate or interact with the element.

Handle Shadow DOM:

If elements are inside a shadow DOM, use Selenium's shadow DOM support or execute_script to access them.

Use Explicit Event Waits:

Wait for specific DOM changes or element states using mutation observers or polling loops.
